# Subtitles for portuguese dialogues

Tags: max-payne-3

Is it possible to get the translation for the portuguese dialogues, or am I supposed to not understand what they're saying? Is it made on purpose to add to the "stranger in a strange land" atmosphere?

Comment: I would have thought they'd include translations at least... but they don't AFAIK.

Comment: It seems like it's on purpose, you only get as much information as the actual main character. There are never cutscenes or similar that give you information that the main character doesn't actually have himself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on PC, you can install a mod by MaxWickedPayne to [add English subtitles for the Portuguese dialogue](https://www.nexusmods.com/maxpayne3/mods/49).

[image: Subtitles for portuguese text]

Alternatively, there is a video by Dual Screens with translations for the in-game dialogue.